# Disabling a submit button if a given field is unfilled in jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, modal-dialog

I am currently using jQuery to disable the submit button on an edit profile section unless the password field is filled in using the following jQuery.

```
$('.submitBtn').prop('disabled', true);
$('.requiredInput').keyup(function() {
    checkRequiredFields();
});
function checkRequiredFields() {
    var count = 0;
    $('.requiredInput').each(function(i){
        if( $(this).val() === '')  count++;
        if(count == 0){
            $('.submitBtn').prop('disabled', false);
        }else {
            $('.submitBtn').prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });
}
```

I also have modal dialog that pops up to show a change password section and I want to disable the submit button on this until data has been entered into the form in a similar way.

If I want to disable one button when one field is empty and another when another field is empty, how might I achieve this?

HTML as requested:

```
     <div class='form-group'>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-sm-6'>
        <label for="user_current_password">Current password</label>
        <input class="form-control requiredInput_1" id="user_current_password" name="user[current_password]" type="password" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
      <input class="btn btn-success submitBtn_1" name="commit" type="submit" value="Save" />
      <a class="btn btn-default" href="/">Cancel</a>
      <div class='btn btn-warning' data-target='#edit-password' data-toggle='modal' style='float:right;'>Change password</div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

And a second form in a modal dialog that is the same.

Comment: What do you mean by `where for example i set submitBtn_1 and submitBtn_2 in the html and loop through these`?

Comment: I have updated the question for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this :

```js
$("input").on('keyup', function(){
    $(this).next().prop('disabled', $(this).val()=="");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input /> <button disabled>ok</button><br>
<input /> <button disabled>ok</button><br>
<input /> <button disabled>ok</button><br>
<input /> <button disabled>ok</button><br>
<input /> <button disabled>ok</button><br>
<input /> <button disabled>ok</button><br>
<input /> <button disabled>ok</button><br>
<input /> <button disabled>ok</button><br>
<input /> <button disabled>ok</button><br>
```

**EDIT**

If the inputs and the buttons are completely apart (in different divs, etc.) you have to set up a little trick to make a connection between them :

```js
$('input').on('keyup', function(e){
  var target = e.currentTarget.attributes['data-btn'].value; // will give you "btn1" or "btn2"
    
  $("#"+target).prop('disabled', $(this).val()=='');
    
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
      <div>
          <div>
              <input data-btn="btn1"/>
          </div>
          <br>
           <div>
              <input data-btn="btn2"/>
          </div>
    </div>
    
    <p>
              <input data-btn="btn3"/>
     </p>
    
    <div>
        <button id="btn1" disabled>BUTTON 1</button>
        <button id="btn2" disabled>BUTTON 2</button>
        <div>
            <button id="btn3" disabled>BUTTON 3</button>
        </div>
    </div>      
</div>
```

Comment: This is really cool, although I'm not sure how to incorporate it into my code as I'm using rails bootstrap forms (f.submit). See my added html

Comment: Hmmm, that's definitely not HTML. Post the actual, built HTML instead of this... preprocessor(?) language

Comment: I have updated my answer with a tougher solution, with a binding between input and button, whererver they are in the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

A better function is

```
$('.requiredInput_1').keyup(function() {
   checkFun(this, ".submitBtn_1");
});

$('.requiredInput_2').keyup(function() {
   checkFun(this, ".submitBtn_2");
});

function checkFun(a, b)
{
        var subBut = $(b);
        $(a).val()==""?subBut.prop('disabled', true):subBut.prop('disabled', false);
}
```

Comment: or `subBut.prop('disabled', $(this).val()=="" )` :)

Comment: Thanks, that is indeed cleaner. If I want to disable one button when one field is empty and another when another field is empty, how might I achieve this?

Comment: See the updated code. Please post your form `html` so that `.submitBtn_1` and `.submitBtn_2` can be calculated automatically as well

Comment: I am ideally looking for a generic way to do this, for example imaging I had 10 fields and buttons I want to do this for, I dont want to create 10 keyup functions.